# how to upload and retrieve photos to firestorage in my fragment?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-fragments, firebase-storage

I searched but when i try to integrate in my project I always get errors in different code blocks. Can you write an example based on the photo I uploaded?

I tried this but i get an error;

```
private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
private lateinit var storageRef: StorageReference
imageView = binding.imageView
        
storageRef.child("images").child("${UUID.randomUUID()}.jpg").putFile(uri)

val galleryImage = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
    if (uri != null) {
        imageView.setImageURI(uri)

        // Upload the image to Firebase Storage
        storageRef.child("${UUID.randomUUID()}.jpg").putFile(uri)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Upload successful
                    Log.e( "hata","Image upload successfull",)
                } else {
                    // Upload failed
                    Log.e( "hata","Image upload failed",)
                }
            }
    }
}

binding.uploadViewbtn.setOnClickListener {
    galleryImage.launch("image/*")
}
```

Comment: What error do you get when you run this code?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error message that you get. Please respond using @.